# Adding Azure o365 group to MS Teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, azure-ad

I am working on a task which requires the involvement of MS Team at a broad level. The scenario related to the issue I am facing is that we have an MS Teams and we would like to add an existing Azure o365 group to it rather than individual users.

The business use case related to this task requires us to manage teams on a regular basis, as most of the time old Users leave and new users join the business, and as we have multiple MS Teams to work with and all the teams will have same set of people in them, it will be much more easier to add the users to one group or remove a user from one group and the changes reflect in all the Teams rather than doing the same with individual teams every time. Managing the Teams on the group level will be much more efficient and easy.

Along with this we also want that when the permission of the group level is changed all the users within that group will get the same permissions.
As I am unable to find a way to implement this, please suggest me a way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not *yet* possible.

On Uservoice, that is currently in fourth place of most wanted feature - with status "in the plans" ([Reference](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/286611-office-365-groups/suggestions/10114956-be-able-to-nest-groups-like-distribution-groups))

---

**Alternative:**

Use [dynamic groups](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-dynamic-membership) for your teams. Membership will be based on user properties, for example which department the users belong to.